# Throw exceptions without needing to use try in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have this Java code that i want to be able to run. It should throw an exception if it have totally been added more than 4 strings, but it should not be needed to use a try/catch the first 4 times the addString method is called.

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.addString("String A");
myFoo.addString("String B");
myFoo.addString("String C");
myFoo.addString("String D");


boolean exceptionThrown = false;

try {
    myFoo.addString("String E");
} catch (NoRoomForMoreStringsException e) {
    exceptionThrown = true;
}

assertTrue(exceptionThrown);
```

If i add something like this in the addString function, it will require me to always use a trow/catch statement.

```
public void addString(String str) throws NoRoomForMoreStringsException {
    ...
    if(strings.size() >= 4) {
        throw new NoRoomForMoreStringsException();  
    }
```

How can i throw an exception in the addString method without needing to always use the try/catch statement?

Comment: Why not just place all the method calls in a single try catch?

Comment: Or if you do not like the exception handling, return a boolean indicating if the action was successful or not.

Comment: Unless you want to make it a `RuntimeException` your question doesn't make sense. If you know which call is going to throw the exception, you don't need the exception, and if you don't know, you don't know where you can omit the try-catch.

Comment: You _can_ declare the calling method as `throws type_covering_exception` and then uncaught potentially-but-not-actually throwing calls compile okay. But this propagates; the next caller(s) up now must either catch an exception that doesn't actually occur, or declare `throws` to _their_ callers. At the extreme you can declare _everything_ `throws Exception` to allow all potential Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i throw an exception in the addString method without needing
>   to always use the try/catch statement ?

You need to declare `NoRoomForMoreStringsException` as `RuntimeException` as shown below:

```
public NoRoomForMoreStringsException extends RuntimeException {

   //methods for custom exception
}
```

In Java, `Exception` objects are two types:

**(1) Checked Exceptions:** 
These exceptions force you to try/catch or declare them in method signature (like your current NoRoomForMoreStringsException). **The best practice is you need to use these Checked exceptions very carefully i.e., only when you have got a recovery action that needs to be done upon catching the exception.**

**(2) Unchecked/Runtime Exceptions :** These exceptions don't force you to catch or declare the exception.

Most of the times, you can prefer using Runtime Exceptions (Type 2 above) because in general, we will be able to do very little (like logging) upon getting an exception.

Because Checked Exceptions are very noisy (means they force the callers either to catch or declare in method signatures), popular frameworks (like `Spring`) try to avoid them i.e., `Spring` throws Runtime Exceptions  or even better wraps/converts the Checked Exceptions (if any from JDK) into Runtime Exceptions and then throws.

**So, in short, if you have got a recovery mechanism, you will go for Checked Exception (Type1 above), otherwise, you need to go for RuntimeException (Type2 above)**

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Comment: I disagree with unchecked exceptions being preferable. It just depends on the context. A `throwspec` becomes part of the method signature and hence how you can use it. As a caller of that method it tells me what exceptions I can expect. If you e.g., decide to throw `IllegalArgumentException` where `FileNotFoundException` would have been more appropriate and you don't document this, you'll probably crash my program and I'll probably stop using your code.

Comment: My point is if you have a recovery plan of action, of course yes, we need to go for checked exception, that's what it is highlighted above.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NoRoomForMoreStringsException` can be an [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). I'm not saying this is a good idea, but it will accomplish what you ask.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler will complain if you do not catch it, but it will still compile and run just fine.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("Starting!");
  Foo myFoo = new Foo();
  myFoo.addString("String A");
  myFoo.addString("String B");
  myFoo.addString("String C");
  myFoo.addString("String D");
  myFoo.addString("String E");
}
```

And the output:

```
Starting!
Adding: String A
Adding: String B
Adding: String C
Adding: String D
Adding: String E
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Foo.addString(Foo.java:6)
    at StackOverFlow.main(StackOverFlow.java:9)
```

Comment: That's a different exception.

Comment: (@Dave) and in particular AIOOBE is a `RuntimeException`, hence unchecked, as already covered in the other answers.